# Electron app won't start, whenready does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, node-modules

I have been going at this for a few days now, I have cloned the electron-quick-start from Electron GitHub(https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) I got this error, but it wasn't only for this app, it was all the apps. I don't know what is happening.
electron latest version: 8.2.0
Error

```
app.whenReady().then(createWindow)
     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'whenReady' of undefined
```

Comment: You should try updating Electron

Comment: ```app.on('ready', createWindow);``` Try to use this at current version.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, per se – I just tried this in an `Electron` project I am currently working on and it worked fine:

```
app.whenReady().then((choice) => {
    console.log("hey, I'm ready", choice);   
})
```

For a reality check, I'd suggest using the ready event:

```
app.on('ready', function () {
  console.log("hey, I'm ready too!");   
});
```

Though it occurs to me to ask: what version of `Electron` are you using? If you are using an pre-7 or 8 version, they hadn't started "promise-ifying" stuff yet (I forget which version started using `Promises`)

Comment: tried that: TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Comment: @Wexion – that's odd. If I encountered that, I'd `console.log(app)` to make sure that `app` was being imported. Doesn't sound like it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your electron version is below v3.0.0.

We can use `whenReady()` from version 3.0.0.
Recommend you to update your electron version.

Comment: Although that is true, I'm not sure if that's the error at hand. On Electron 2, you would get a `TypeError: app.whenReady is not a function` error for this case. It seems like for the user, `app` itself is undefined.

Comment: Well, the app is available at v2. Just there is no declared whenReady function inside app.

Comment: anyhow, I wonder why @Wexion is facing such error if he is using the right quick-start repo.

Comment: Actually, this starter repo is using electron v8. And seems working pretty good.

Comment: idk, is my node or electron installation messed up, I did do npm i --save-dev electron

Comment: @Wexion Please show me your node version and try to like this ```rm -rf node_modules```, ```rm -rf package-lock.json```, ```rm -rf yarn.lock```, ```npm install``` at your project directory

Comment: And you don't need to ```npm I --save-dev electron```.

Comment: node version: v13.12.0, I did ```m -rf node_modules, rm -rf package-lock.json, rm -rf yarn.lock, npm install``` still getting that "TypeError: Cannot read property 'whenReady' of undefined"

Comment: GitHub issue on electron Quickstart not me but same issue (https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/issues/370)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `node main.js` or `npx nodemon main.js`

- USE: `npx electron .`

Problem fixed my mate!

Answer (score 0):

I am also stuck with this error. But I am found the answer in 30 mins. This error is occurred when you running your app through this command `node main.js` But You must run your app using this command `npm start` command bcoz start will excute `electron .` .
The package.json must be

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Event Managemnt System",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "John Doe",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^24.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, please add additional details... How can your answer address the question?

Comment: Electron is global executable file. And then you can't run run your electron app using node (.exe) . When you trigger nom start command at the time electron will execute your app.